# Line breaks on seperated Tags

Tags: 7

When I comma seperate my tags to make individual tags, drupal tend to put a linebreak behind every individual tag.

What happens:

[image: automatic <br> add by Drupal]

That means that I need to make 1 huge tag, which is not factual.

I am Pretty newbie when it comes to drupal but this is kinda annoying.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to correct it with css. Does the code actually prints a line brake some thing like <br> ?

Comment: @MohammedShameem No, that's actually the point. When adding content, the tag description says: seperate the tags with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

This is just how out of the box drupal styles the tags fields.

You can fix it by overriding the themeing of your tags in your theme, but the easiest way I have seen to fix it is by using the [Text list formatter](https://drupal.org/project/textformatter) module.

Install that then go to the display settings for your content type and there will be a new option "List", which then has further configuration options that can give you the output you desire.